# Clearing wordpress caching not working, shows the old page unable to clear cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, cache-control

I redesigned my wordpress site recently but fortunately/unfortunately i had some sort of caching plugin installed on it which is causing the first load page (the home page) to show as the older version. Only on reload is it showing the right (Updated home) page.

Heres what i already tried:

- Clearing server side caching
- Tried to set cache to past using .htaccess (Obviously Failed - 500 Internal Error)
- Had my server rebooted
- Installed many plugins to Clear the cache (Ofc none worked so uninstalled them too)
- Checked if i had some cached content using cache checker (image below)(Home page is cached for 30 days)
  [image: https://www.giftofspeed.com/cache-checker/]
- checked with gtmetrix.com (image below)(CACHED TILL 3RD AUG & theres 22 days to go still)
  [image: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/sugarswap.in/1Z401LB0]
- i tried deleting cached files from the file directories manually, searched but couldn't find whatever is actually causing it.

I am at a loss, need the updated page to show earliest possible and im unable to clear this caching issue. If its of any help/ clue the gtmetrix image gives a link

`<https://www.sugarswap.in/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://www.sugarswap.in/>; rel=shortlink`

I am also including how the page should look and how it is looking on first load on both mobile and desktop below.

**Desktop (Old)**
[image: OLD VERSION OF THE SITE]
**Desktop (NEW)**
[image: NEW VERSION OF THE SITE]

**Mobile (Old)**--------------------------------------------------------------**Mobile (NEW)**

[image: OLD MOBILE VERSION (UNDERCONTRUCTION PAGE)]
[image: NEW MOBILE VERSION OF THE SITE]

**UPDATE:(12th Jul 2020 05:27pm IST)**

I tried this plugin called "Proxy Cache Purge" and checked via it and the following was the result it gave.
Note how it has the same `https://api.w.org/` in link and X-server-cache as `true`. Well the plugin itself didn't help purging the cache anyway, So i am STILL stuck. :(
[image: Proxy Cache Purge URL Check Results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try to put into your wp-config.php file this:

```
define('WP_CACHE', false)
```

Comment: Try to disable all plugins

Comment: I have noticed you have Jetpack could you please disable it?

Comment: i did disable all plugins as you mentioned, including jetpack.. no change.

Comment: is the site having a multisite or something else that we dont know? I also recommend that you go into your theme and add to every css and js file ?v=1.1

Comment: its not a multisite, just a plain old wordpress site. i tried to search around how thats done, i couldn't get a clear grasp of it, im kinda new at versioning(?).. I've never done it before, so can you guide me to any tutorial or something? i'll try it out..

Comment: Does this work if I place it inside functions.php? I don't have any wp-config.php file.

Comment: wp-config.php is in the root of your project, that file should be there

Answer (score 0):

For clear cache use Wp Fastest cache wordpress plugin . i hope it will help you

Comment: i tried this before along with WP Super Cache, LiteSpeed Cache & Proxy Cache Purge. Regardless i tried it again and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all assure that the problem is in cache. Open from another browser or from another computer and see what data loads. If the clean site opens, then the problem is in the cache. But if the same data loads then the problem is maybe in reusing the old site, or starting from old location, from old database. If this is the case then fix the error. If not, the problem is in the cache. 
If the problem is in the cache press F12 in browser, switch to the tab application, click on Clear storage and there click "Clear site data".
[image]

Comment: i didn't get what you meant by `clean site opens` and `same data loads`.. i tried opening the site in numerous devices and multiple times after reinstalling browsers. Everytime I open the site it shows the older version of it first, and only upon reloading the site without closing the browser does it show the updated one. Tho as soon as i close the **Browser** and reopen it, it repeats the same thing all over.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/36rr7.png
This one seems to suggest there is a caching expiring on 3rd tho? :\

Also i tried the suggestion you proposed too, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @PrithviSoma be attentive. I suggested to check if the problem is in the cache. Maybe it is not in the cache. Maybe you are opening the wrong site. Or maybe in Apache is set the wrong folder to use. Or maybe your site use the wrong database. Check attentively each option.

Comment: its definitely not the wrong site if you are referring to a mistake in url/domain name.. and Apache is set to the right folder, i checked.. (side que - would it still show the updated site even if Apache was set to wrong folder on reloading the same url which was showing old version of the page?).. And Database is also set alright. the site is working perfectly fine for those who are coming to the site after reloading the page and some have even placed orders without an issue too..

Comment: @PrithviSoma It is definitely the wrong site. There doesn't exist any magic in programming. If you search what did you wrong you will find out. Investigate the right direction which definitely is not the caching.

Comment: why do you think it is the wrong site? and if it really is (which i don't think i'd get my own site wrong..) how do i confirm it.. please guide.

Comment: @PrithviSoma because there is no magic under the hood. Everything is a consequence of something natural. If you investigate in the right direction you will find out for sure. Btw, it might be also the hosts file that directs you to the wrong site. But it is the wrong site, not the caching.

Comment: i understand that its no magic.. but as you can see i am still new to this and i need to know how to fix it.. like i stated earlier, i have a feeling that wp is getting an old backup copy/ cached copy from `https://api.w.org/`.. but i've no idea where thats happening and i've been at it since past 7 days.. i've checked _.htaccess, wp-config.php, wp-settings.php, index.php, wp-blog-header.php, wp-cron.php, wp-load.php_ and quite a lot more files.. i just can't seem to find where.. :\

Comment: @PrithviSoma Not the cache. You are somewhere pointing to the wrong site. Is it Apache (check httpd.conf), is it hosts file(search the internet about what is hosts file), is it the wrong database, is it the wrong file. I don't know. It is clearly used the old site instead of new one. You have to do your investigations now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A1
    Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
</IfModule>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.